# Protect individual static files in ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net, authentication, single-page-application, static-files

I have an requirement where I have to protect individual static files in an ASP.NET (not ASP.NET Core, yet) application.

**Background:** We have a SPA (Angular) which will be deployed into the /dist folder on the server. On the same application some REST APIs and SignalR hubs are hosted. Access to the REST APIs is protected with OAuth bearer token (JWT). Access to the static files is unprotected. The SPA is in such a way implemented that it itself handles authentication and authorization via OIDC/OAuth (MSAL.js). The SPA talks to our hosted REST APIs and also to others hosted elsewhere (also protected via OAuth).

Our customer ordered a security auditor. They came back with a report about security findings. One of which regarding the application logic of the SPA. It's unprotected (shock). Everyone can look into it (shock). The security auditor suggests a non protected landing page. When the users log in then they are forwarded to the full blown SPA. Only authenticated users can see the application logic (not really a security gain in my opinion).

My job is to make an analysis how we can achieve the proposal and how much cost will be involved with the change.

The dev team consists of front-end developers (Node.js people) who don't have any knowledge about ASP.NET. My thought was to let them develop the landing page which will be at the end most-likely a static file.

So my question is whether it is possible to configure the ASP.NET application such that access to static landing page is unprotected but access to the static app is protected.

For reference I will add part of web.config and Startup.cs.

```xml
<rule name="Rewrite Static Assets" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="{regex for static files}" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/dist/(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/dist/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

```c#
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ConfigureWebApi(app);
    ConfigureSignalR(app);
}

private static void ConfigureWebApi(IAppBuilder app)
{
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    WebApiConfig.Register(config);

    string b2cTenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:DashboardTenant"];
    string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:SignalRB2cAudience"];
    string policy = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["B2C AAD Policy"];

    var tvps = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidAudience = clientId,
        AuthenticationType = policy
    };

    var oidcConfUrl = string.Format($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{b2cTenant}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p={policy}");
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AccessTokenFormat = new JwtFormat(
            tvps,
            new OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider(oidcConfUrl))
    });

    app.UseWebApi(config);
}

private static void ConfigureSignalR(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.Map("/signalr", map =>
    {
        map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        map.RunSignalR();
    });
}
```